# How to write [UITableViewCell class] in swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

How to write `[UITableViewCell class]` in Swift?
In Swift, I tried using `UITableViewCell.class()`, but it's crossed out. I'm wondering what is the equivalent method to use. I'm trying to invoke the `self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.class(), forCellReuseIdentifier: defaultCellIdentifier)` method in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `UITableViewCell.class()`, try `UITableViewCell.self` in Swift.

Comment: What array? `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` does not ask for an array anywhere, nor does its Swift equivalent.